# « Solution triviale » (maths)

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, usage

En mathématiques, peut-on employer **solution triviale** comme traduction de l'anglais ***trivial solution*** ou existe-t-il des expressions plus adéquates ?

Par exemple :

> Solution élémentaire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il est possible d'utiliser "solution triviale" comme traduction, ou bien si tu veux changer tu peux aussi dire "solution évidente".

Comment: Ça n'apporte rien à la discussion mais je suis totalement d'accord avec Reda. J'ajouterais que ça peut aussi s'appliquer à d'autres domaines scientifiques